# textbox in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can i bind my data with textbox in asp.net using c#
sorry to ask this silly question

if yes than how to bind it 
as if we use VC# the text box has the option data binding in property ''

in asp.net i am not getting it

plz can any help me out ?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+databinding, and http://asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the value of the database providers to textbox, the process could be like this,

```
 DataSet ds = mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds,"xyz");

 txtName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NameField"].ToString();
 txtField2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Field2"].ToString();
```

Even from the Data Reader you can bind the data to textbox in the similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It's been possible since ASP.NET 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# function could be:

```
void Page_Load() { 
 txt1.Text = "Hello World"; 
}
```

Your ASP.NET code could be:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: bro i wanna bind my database with it so this not i want